# Tags about CSPs

Tags: discussion, tags

Should [constraint-satisfaction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constraint-satisfaction) and [constraint-programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constraint-programming) be merged?
What about [constraint-handling-rules](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constraint-handling-rules)?

Comment: That seems reasonnable, since the first has no question at all, and the last has only 3 questions, two of which also having the [tag:constraint-programming] tag.

Comment: Actually, the first was a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: I could have corrected that myself, but my brain autocorrect did not see the typo… Now to compare the first two tags, they are obviously related, One could argue that the first one is more theoretical and the second one aims to solve efficiently problems of the first, but in practice, after checking some questions of [tag:constraint-satisfaction], it seems that posters are mainly asking about algorithms and programming, so the merging still sound reasonnable.